# iOS Simulator crashing mac after a few seconds of use

Tags: ios, macos, ios-simulator

This is such a strange issue, but lately I can't start the iOS Simulator without it crashing my Mac and me needing to unmount the HD, repair it, and then restart.

When iOS Simulator is running, after a few seconds, a bunch of colored lines start appearing on the screen as tiny tears and then the screen splits in half and either turns gray or blue with black lines. The first couple of times I could close the simulator in time and the screen would revert back to normal, but after a few times it's almost an immediate crash with almost no chance of trying to close the simulator. When I restart, I can't get past the grey screen and need to go into recovery mode. I have a 2GHz i7 MacBook Pro with 16GB memory running OS X 10.9.1.

Does anyone have any ideas at all what is causing this?

Comment: Do you still have this problem even after the 'repair disk'?

Comment: I do, unfortunately. But using the disk utility seems to repair it each time.

Comment: You should probably reinstall Xcode after deleting it, and if that doesn't work then reinstall the operating system after reformatting the hard drive. And it isn't necessarily a problem with the iOS Simulator that is causing the corruption, it could just be that that's the scenario that triggers it. But with what's been posted here, it's impossible to know what's actually happening.

Comment: Right, I've used several different simulators and different apps and it still crashes. I've tried running games, movies, etc. all simultaneously and it's on the simulator that does it. I'll go ahead and reinstall everything and see if it helps but in the meantime was hoping someone here has ran across this before. Thanks @Gavin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was that widespread GPU issue that most early 2011 MacBooks have. I've taken it to get it's logic board replaced as it's the only fix. I should have Googled this before asking, but if you're here reading this then you're smarter than I am. Good work.

Comment: Do you have a link/info about this? Where can I find more information about it?

Comment: Sure, check out [this link](http://www.cultofmac.com/262861/early-2011-macbook-pros-dropping-like-flies-heat-issues-blame/) for more info.

Answer (score -2):

Because of security issues you have to update to 10.9.2 ASAP if you're really on 10.9.1